# Low and High DWORD => size_t

Tags: c, join, size-t, dword

Programming language: C

I have two DWORDs: A low and a high one. I want to convert them both into one variable of type size_t. I have the following code:

```
size_t fileSize = fileSizeHigh;
size_t *pfileSize = &fileSize;
pfileSize[4] = fileSizeLow;
```

is it right that way? I guess not since the first command probably stores the high-byte in the wrong position, right? Please help me on how to do this. Thank You :)

Answer (score 2):

So, on a 32-bit Microsoft system, a `DWORD` is the same size as a `size_t`. This means that you cannot fit two `DWORD`s into the space occupied by a `size_t`.

Your code will simply write into memory beyond the end of `fileSize` and has undefined behaviour. It will not do what you want.

What is it you're actually trying to accomplish? What is the task you are trying to complete? Tell us that and we may be able to offer you an alternate solution.

**Edit**: As @nos explains, on a 64-bit system a `size_t` can hold two `DWORD`s. If you're using a 64-bit system, you can use bit shifting to combine the two:

```
size_t combined = ((size_t)high << 32) | (size_t)low; // 64-BIT WINDOWS ONLY
```

However, this is still a bit of a code smell, because operations on 64-bit Windows targets are meant to be very similar to those on 32-bit targets, so it still looks like you're doing something for an odd reason.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing 64 bit code, a size_t is normally 64 bit. You need to verify this on your platform. A DWORD is usually 32 bit, you need to verify that too. Given 32 bit DWORD and 64 bit size_t, you do this:

```
DWORD a = ...;
DWORD b = ...;
size_t c = (size_t)a << 32 | b;
```

If you're writing 32 bit code, it would not make sense to combine 2 32 bit types into another 32 bit type, size_t is normally 32 bit in 32 bit code.

Comment: Thank You. Yes, I'm on a 64bit system(Win7 x64). Is there an alternative to size_t that is 64bit in size independent of the OS?

Comment: `unsigned __int64` is the alternative type. *But if you tell us what you're trying to do*, we may be able to help you figure out a better approach.

Comment: Thanks. I want to read out the size of a file. To achieve this I'm first opening the file using CreateFile. Then I'm reading out the size with GetFileSize. As a result I get a low and a high DWORD. Finally I want to join them. (yes, I know my code isn't portable since I'm using WinAPI)